# can you explain to me this php warning about https

Tags: php, dom, https

I received the following warning, when I tried to access a file from gitub in PHP script:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]:
>           Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you
>           configured PHP? 
>           in C:\xampp\htdocs\plaoul\text\gittest.php on line 13`

Can you explain what "wrapper" is, what needs to be configured, and generally what's happening?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrappers are classes made to access data streams through various protocols, in this case, HTTPS. Read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php

You need the HTTP/HTTPS wrapper: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php, plus PHP built with SSL support.

Does `php -m |grep openssl` return anything?

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment `php_openssl.dll` extension in the `php.ini` then restart apache.

In some additions of xampp this line is missing and has to manually inserted!

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: I don't see `php_openssl.dll` in my `php.ini` file -- hmm